# Proof Check: In a positive measure space, the measure of a union of an increasing chain of sets is equal to the limit of the measure of the sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

In my textbook Johnsonbaugh/Pfaffenberger - Foundations of Mathematical Analysis, we prove that if $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq \dots $ with each $A_n$ in the sigma-algebra $M$, then $\mu (\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$. However, we also prove that $A \subseteq B \implies \mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$, where $\mu$ is the measure on $M$. I'm wondering if this alternative proof also works:

We have that $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i \subseteq A_n \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i$. Therefore $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq \mu(A_n) \leq \mu(\cup_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i)$. Taking limits, we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_n) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\cup_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i)$. Therefore, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(\cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i) = \mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)$.

My textbook subtracts out the inclusions and then uses pairwise disjointness to use the countable additivity of $\mu$ to establish equality, but if this way works it seems to be more natural to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the positive measure $\mu:[0,\infty]$ closed under limits, and so the fact that the sets are increasing means that either they satisfy the increasing chain condition and will have a finite measure or fail to satisfy it and will have measure $= \infty$?

Comment: @metamorphy right, but I don't think I lose anything by taking the weaker statement, and I'm not sure if I could use the reasoning that since they're equal at each finite $n$ that they'll be equal in the limit. That feels like too strong a statement, but I'm quite possibly wrong

Comment: @tmaths also, I don't see where I defined the limit of a set sequence? My limits take place in the nonnegative extended real line, no?

Comment: Ah thank you. I'm still fairly new to this site, should I leave this as is since I can't check off an answer in a comment?

Comment: It is rather me... posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the very last equality in your derivation. It is *not* a definition of $\mu(\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n)$ - it is exactly what needs a proof.

Comment: Thank you again!